# resize /dev/loop0 and increase space

Tags: partitioning, mount

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       2765720 2393576    231652  92% /
udev              496568      12    496556   1% /dev
tmpfs             202148     796    201352   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              505368      80    505288   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda7       13632464 8209984   5422480  61% /host
/dev/loop1       4031680 2452148   1374732  65% /usr
```

ThIs is the output of df command. How do I increase the avalable in dev/loop0 or may be resize it.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `sudo losetup /dev/loop0` to see what file the loopback device is attached to, then you can increase its size with, for example, `sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1MiB of=/path/to/file conv=notrunc oflag=append count=xxx` where xxx is the number of MiB you want to add.  After that, `sudo losetup -c /dev/loop0` and `sudo resize2fs /dev/loop0` should make the new space available for use.

Comment: This made my ubuntu 14.04 system very unstable.

Comment: if the file system is `xfs` try `xfs_growfs` instead of `resize2fs`. To identify if the file system of the loop device use `blkid`

Answer (score 3):

To to see what file the loopback device is attached to, execute:

```
# losetup /dev/loop0
```

then to increase its size you can give, for example

```
# dd if=/dev/zero bs=1MiB of=/path/to/file conv=notrunc oflag=append count=xxx
```

where `xxx` is the number of *MiB* you want to add.

If the file system is not currently mounted on `/`, to make the new space available for use you can give:

```
# losetup -c /dev/loop0
# resize2fs /dev/loop0
```

If the image you are trying to resize is Ubuntu Touch/Ubports `rootfs` (which is found in `/data/system.img`) and you are trying to do this from the device, now reboot to `recovery` and then after entering in the device with `adb shell`, give:

```
# losetup /dev/block/loop0 /data/system.img
# e2fsck -f /dev/block/loop0
# resize2fs -f /dev/block/loop0     # if your fs is ext
# xfs_growfs /dev/block/loop0       # if your fs is xfs
```

Comment: This solution works perfect, thanks, i only use a different string for dd `dd if=/dev/null of=/userdata/system.img bs=1M seek=3000 count=0`, this enlarge my partition to 3G(original was 2G, sic!)

Answer (score 1):

worked for me, 4Gb

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1MiB of=/userdata/system.img conv=notrunc oflag=append count=4200
sudo e2fsck -yf /userdata/system.img
sudo resize2fs -f /userdata/system.img 1024000
```

Comment: This worked for me. It doesn't use the loop device, but it solves the problem (resizing the image).