# Ubuntu touch – /etc/fstab resets after every restart

Tags: mount, ubuntu-touch, fstab, phone, meizu-mx4

I have just received the Meizu MX4 Ubuntu edition and have already started hacking it. Managed to use davfs2 to mount remote drives ok, but anything I add to /etc/fstab is automatically removed every time the phone is restarted. Is this a bug or a deliberate security feature?

Is there a workaround? – was thinking of having a script run after startup, grep /etc/fstab and append line(s) that are missing, then mount drives. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `/lib/init/fstab`. But before we should set a system partition as writable:

```
sudo android-gadget-service enable writable
```

After rebooting we can edit `/lib/init/fstab` with `sudo nano` or `sudo vim`, for example we can add this string:

```
/dev/mmcblk1p2  /home/phablet/mnt/sd      ext2            defaults,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

to mount ext2 partition on sd card. Then, we make system partition read-only again: `sudo rm /userdata/.writable_image` and reboot.

Of course, after getting new OTA we should repeat it again.

Standard `/etc/fstab` is mystical in ubuntu-touch, mounting (binding) to tmpfs and seems is generated on-the-fly or just in starting. But `/lib/init/fstab` works well.