# own libertine container in the custom directory or partition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, fstab, m10, libertine

Is there a way to install own libertine container in the custom directory or partition? I think the main size (volume) of container installation belongs to directory like this:

```
/home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/my-container/rootfs
```

Of course it will be helpful to know a list of other file locations of own container like:

```
~/.local/share/libertine/ContainersConfig.json
~/.cache/libertine-container/my-container
~/.cache/my-container
~/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/my-container
~/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/my-container/.cach/libertine-container/my-container
```

I see now only way with using `mount --bind..`, but in doing that we have several problems [here with `/etc/fstab` editing or using `/etc/rc.local`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739915)  or [upstart script to automount on device starting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613557).

So, **second question** is that: if I use `mount --bind..` for binding  `/home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/my-container/rootfs`
manually from time to time, then **will I have a trouble with correct work of libertine scope** ([like as described there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/today-scope/+bug/1626180))?

Comment: Your intent is to create a non-libertine container for libertine to use? I would not recommend it. Would it be possible to make whatever changes you need to a libertine-managed container?

Comment: Larry, my idea is to place ``rootfs`` of particular libertine container on SD card and use it with ``mount --bind``. And I've solved this problem. So, I'll present my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before our actions we should have SD card with `ext2/3/4` partition. In Ubuntu Touch it can be represented as `/dev/mmcblk1p2` (in my case). If we want permanent mounting, we can’t use `/etc/fstab/` but we can use `/lib/init/fstab` as I [pointed in answer there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646640/ubuntu-touch-etc-fstab-resets-after-every-restart/849928#84992849928). Permanent mounting of SD in Ubuntu Touch is not convenient and not stable. Sometimes, because of error in file system on ext2 partition, I had got problems with booting of Ubuntu Touch. Perhaps, shooting down of device doesn't perform dismounting correctly. So, I decided to mount SD card and to use Libertine container on it from time to time.

At first, I created new container with name `sd-container` as usual in internal disk space: `/home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/sd-container`. Then, I mounted ext2 partition on SD with such command:

```
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p2 /home/phablet/mnt/sd -t ext2 -o defaults,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro
```

then I made directory `/home/phablet/mnt/sd/sd-container/` and made copy of rootfs of sd-container to  ext2 partition on SD:

```
cd /home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/sd-container
rsync -aAXvH ./ /home/phablet/mnt/sd/sd-container/
```

After this preparing I made script to mount  ext2 partition on SD and to bind rootfs (`sdgo.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p2 /home/phablet/mnt/sd -t ext2 -o defaults,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro
sudo mount --bind  /home/phablet/mnt/sd/sd-container/rootfs /home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/sd-container/rootfs
restart unity8-dash
```

and script to stop playng with this (`sdstop.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo umount /home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/sd-container/rootfs
sudo umount /dev/mmcblk1p2
restart unity8-dash
```

Finally, after I run `sdgo.sh` unity8-dash restarts, and I can see new SD-container scope and its applications under Desktop App Scope. I can run or install new applications as usual. But rootfs of this container is situated on SD card! When I want to stop I run `sdstop.sh` and SD-container scope disappears. And small original `rootfs` (hidden by this binding) remains on internal disk space without changes.

**Conclusion:** I have rootfs of Libertine container on SD card and possibility to switch on/off it and its scope when I want.