# How can I install Tor on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch, proxy, tor, click-packages

I'm running Ubuntu Touch r62 on my Nexus 4, and I'm wondering how I can go about installing Tor. I've gone ahead and put my Nexus 4 in write-mode with `phablet-config writeable-image` and can install packages with `apt`, however I'm limited by the 2GB root partition (`/dev/loop0`) and have no space to install substantially sized software.

`click` seems to install packages outside of the root partition where there is actually space, but I haven't had luck finding a click package for Tor anywhere. I'm also not sure how Tor would work if it were containerised in a click package.

My intention is for a native QML application that I'm building to have access to Tor via a proxy such as Tor SOCKS.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**For end-useres:**
At present time we should use Libertine to run usual X- and console applications. If you have not yet Libertine on device then [read Ubuntu Wiki about Libertine](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Libertine) and, for example, article of [Kyle Nitzsche](http://kylenubuntu.blogspot.ru/2016/07/running-x-apps-on-ubuntu-devices.html). If Libertine is on device you should create your own container and install firefox and tor package with command like this:

```
libertine-container-manager install-package --id my-container --package tor
```

details see in [Kyle's article](http://kylenubuntu.blogspot.ru/2016/07/running-x-apps-on-ubuntu-devices.html). Then see [how to configure and use Tor on Linux](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-unix.html.en#using).

Additionally, you can see topic [how to use Libertine container on SD card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844266/own-libertine-container-in-the-custom-directory-or-partition).

Comment: I should clarify, I don't want to use libertine, since that is also containerised in its own chroot. My understanding is that if tor is installed in a libertine container, then other applications won't be able to access its proxy through tor socks. My intention is for a native qml application I'm building to be able to access tor through an optional in-app proxy configuration. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: qml browser on device hasn't option to set proxy, even if you install tor in system partition. Firefox works only via Libertine. So, Libertine is not so bad choice. In any case, there is nothing about Libertine in first question. In your own chroot you can install the whole  distro, like Mint, [see there](https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z12qhb4pcnv3xxine221zrmbbqe4grkdd)

Comment: Of course you can install tor in base system, for example, via ``apt-get install tor`` (if you have system partition writable). But usually, it is not good way for Ubuntu Touch (and qml browser without proxy, too)

Comment: Are you suggesting that there is no API to set a proxy for internet access on Ubuntu Touch? My intention is not to make the default browser work with Tor, but rather I am developing my own application which requires optional Tor capabilities... `apt` is not a great way to install Tor because of the limited system partition, but it may be the way I go for now.

Comment: QtWebKit has such API, about recent QtWebEngine (or someone, which used in Ubuntu Touch browser -- I don't know, but think it should have). I mean default browser! And [tor package in Ubuntu isn't so big, see list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/tor/filelist).