# Time it takes to resize /dev/loop0 and increase space

Tags: resize

I followed the steps in [resize /dev/loop0 and increase space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260620/resize-dev-loop0-and-increase-space) to resize my `/dev/loop0`.

I gave the command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1MiB of=/path/to/file conv=notrunc oflag=append count=100000
```

This took around an hour to complete.
Here I've replaced the `/path/to/file` from what I obtained in `sudo losetup /dev/loop0`.
After this I gave the command `sudo losetup -c /dev/loop0`, which made my system freeze and its in this state since more than 14 hours.

I do not want to do something stupid at this point. Can somebody tell me what I should do?
The system is responding to ping packets but is not allowing ssh from remote systems.
The original `/dev/loop0` partition was 29GB.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of this is that you had less than 100 GB free space on the directory `/path/to/file`. In other words, you are appending 100 GB to `/dev/loop0` from the home directory in which Ubuntu is installed (given by `/path/to/file`). But you have less than 100 GB free space in `/path/to/file` so as a result it is eating up the space on the memory. You can check the space available in `/path/to/file` by GParted. Hope this answers your question.